# Achieving complete anonymity in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Each User has_many Personas, each Persona belongs_to a User. Users can create and destroy new Personas whenever they want. Users sign in/create a new session with the traditional email/password combination, and can then operate as whichever of their personas they choose (users are allowed up to 3 personas - called 'Dominos' on the website).

Each Persona operates just like a user would on any other website (profile pic, making posts, sending messages etc). I want it to be impossible to determine which User each Persona belongs to. My question is, how can this be achieved?

Moreover, I don't want any link between Personas. I therefore think it is necessary to ensure that the Persona id cannot be determined. If a user creates say three Personas in quick succession, they would probably have consecutive Persona id's, so you could make the reasonable guess that Personas with consecutive Persona id's were probably created by the same user.

The friendly_id gem hides id's in the URL but can they still be identified by some means?

What other considerations should there be?  I don't really know where to begin with this anonymity objective.

### Edit

This is what I have:

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one  :ghost,    dependent: :destroy
  has_many :personas, dependent: :destroy

  before_create :create_remember_token
  before_save do
    email.downcase!
    callsign.downcase!
  end
  after_save do
    self.create_ghost unless ghost
  end

  validates :name, presence: true,
                   length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
                    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  VALID_CALLSIGN_REGEX = /\A[a-z\d\-.\_]+\z/i
  validates :callsign, presence:   true,
                       length:     { maximum: 20 },
                       format:     { with: VALID_CALLSIGN_REGEX },
                       uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

  has_secure_password

  def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def User.digest(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
  end

  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = User.digest(User.new_remember_token)
    end

end
```

Users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :signed_in_user,     only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :non_signed_in_user, only: [:new, :create]
  before_action :correct_user,       only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,         only: :destroy

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @page_name = "user_page"
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome, " + @user.name
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end # create

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if ( current_user != @user )
      @user.destroy
      flash[:success] = "User deleted."
      redirect_to users_url
    else
      redirect_to @user, notice: "Suicide is not permitted, admin chappie. Hard cheese."
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end # update

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :callsign, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Before filters

    def non_signed_in_user
      if signed_in?
        redirect_to root_url, notice: "Nice try pal. You can't create a new user 
                                       if you're already signed in."
      end
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end

end
```

Persona model:

```
class Persona < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  before_save :make_downcase_callsign

  validates :name, presence: true,
                   length:   { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_CALLSIGN_REGEX = /\A[a-z\d\-.\_]+\z/i
  validates :callsign, presence:   true,
                       length:     { maximum: 20 },
                       format:     { with: VALID_CALLSIGN_REGEX },
                       uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :persona_id, presence: true

  private

    def make_downcase_callsign
      return unless callsign
      self.callsign = callsign.downcase
    end

end # Persona
```

Personas controller:

```
class PersonasController < ApplicationController

  before_action :signed_in_user
  before_action :correct_persona,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_destroyer, only: :destroy
  before_action :too_many_personas, only: :create

  def index
    @personas = Persona.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @persona = Persona.find(params[:id])
    @page_name = "domino_" + @persona.persona_id.to_s + "_page"
  end

  def new
    @persona = Persona.new
  end

  def create
    @persona = current_user.personas.build(persona_params)
    set_persona_id
    if @persona.save
      flash[:success] = "This is the moment of your creation, " + @persona.name
      redirect_to @persona
    else
      render 'new'
      end
  end

  def edit
    @persona = Persona.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @persona = Persona.find(params[:id])
    if @persona.update_attributes(persona_params)
      flash[:success] = "Persona profile updated"
      redirect_to @persona
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @persona = Persona.find(params[:id])
    @persona.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Persona deleted."
    redirect_to current_user
  end


  private

    def persona_params
      params.require(:persona).permit(:name, :callsign)
    end

    def correct_persona
      @persona = Persona.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.id == @persona.user_id
    end

    def correct_destroyer
      @persona = Persona.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless ( (current_user.id == @persona.user_id) || current_user.admin? )
    end

    def too_many_personas
      if ( current_user.personas.count >= 3 )
        flash[:message] = "Sorry, you're not allowed more than three dominos."
        redirect_to(root_url)
      end
    end

    def set_persona_id
      if ( current_user.personas.count == 0 )
        @persona.persona_id = 1
        return
      end
      if ( current_user.personas.count == 1 )
        if current_user.personas.first.persona_id == 1
          @persona.persona_id = 2
          return
        else
          @persona.persona_id = 1
          return
        end
      end
      if ( current_user.personas.count == 2 )
        if current_user.personas.first.persona_id == 1
          if current_user.personas.second.persona_id == 2
            @persona.persona_id = 3
            return
          else
            @persona.persona_id = 2
            return
          end
        end
        if current_user.personas.first.persona_id == 2
          if current_user.personas.second.persona_id == 1
            @persona.persona_id = 3
            return
          else
            @persona.persona_id = 1
            return
          end
        end
        if current_user.personas.first.persona_id == 3
          if current_user.personas.second.persona_id == 1
            @persona.persona_id = 2
            return
          else
            @persona.persona_id = 1
            return
          end
        end
      end
    end

end # class PersonasController < ApplicationController
```

I want to know how to organise everything so a malevolent user cannot determine which persona belongs to which user. The idea is that a user can create as many personas as he likes, and there is no connection between them apparent to other (possibly malevolent) users.

Comment: You need to clarify what you have now and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Can you not solve the consecutive id issue by forcing Rails to use UUIDs instead of integers as primary keys?

Comment: Yes I think that would work. But would this help prevent the identification of which personas belong to which user?

Comment: It depends who may see that and why. I think you're missing authorization logic. Leaving this UUID thing for now, if a user `A` would type `/persona/4` which is user `B` persona actually and user `A` musn't see it, then it is just a matter of permissions who may see what and why. Now, comparing UUID's to any authorization logic. Is it possible that user `A` may guess user `B` persona UUID? Yes, but unlikely. Is it possible that user `A` may see user `B` persona account with any given authorization system? No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that this is going to fully answer your question, because I don't think that you've defined the scope of your problem well enough.

But let's think through, at a high level, what should be true of an application that would guarantee my anonymity as a user.

1)  No user should be able to discern my identify through a URL.

- This seems straightforward enough.  If each Persona has a randomly generated key associated with it, and that key is used as the id in the URL, then this condition should be satisfied.

2)  No user should be able to reverse engineer my identity through site behavior.

- This is a bit trickier.  You'd want to make sure that you're not tracking any information about IP address of login (I think Devise does this, if you're using that gem), because that could be a problem.
- Additionally, you might want to think about whether you want to timestamp any behavior of that persona, since you could at least reverse engineer the likely side of the world someone is on from those timestamps.
- You'd also want to avoid using any third parties for site analytics (e.g. Google Analytics), since that would defeat the whole point.

3)  If a bad guy obtained a copy of the database, he/she should not be able to reverse engineer a Persona's identity.

- Now we're having fun!  Obviously you're hashing passwords, but now we want to be encrypting any uniquely identifiable information.  This means names, usernames, emails, dates of birth, etc.  There's a gem that I really like called symmteric encryption (https://github.com/reidmorrison/symmetric-encryption) which splits your encryption key into two separate parts, so that someone would need your database, your ruby code, and a separate key file to put it all back together.

4)  Other features

- I don't know if you're familiar with Kinja (it's a commenting platform), but they have an idea of a burner account.  Basically, you create a username, get a 16-digit key as a password, but then you can't change that password or recover it if it's lost.  From an anonymity standpoint, it's good in the sense that if someone gained access to your email, they couldn't use a "Forgot your password?" feature as a means of gaining access to that burner account.  So depending on your needs, you could implement something like that.

5)  SSL

- Obviously, you would want every aspect of your site to be behind SSL.

Those are just the main considerations I would have of anything that claimed to be "anonymous".  It really comes down to what level of anonymity you're trying to guarantee though.  This would all be an *INSANE* level of anonymity for a blogging site, but woefully inadequate from a thwarting-the-NSA perspective.  So consider your audience!